# How to use type constructor in infix form

Tags: haskell, syntax

I am going through [some Haskell documentation](https://wiki.haskell.org/Constructor), and found the statement

> You can declare a constructor (**for both type and data**) to be an infix operator, and this can make your code a lot more readable.

I am able to use data constructor in infix form like below:

```
Prelude> data List a = Empty | a :-> (List a) deriving Show
Prelude> 
Prelude> let var1 = 10 :-> Empty
Prelude> let var2 = 20 :-> var1
Prelude> let var3 = 30 :-> var2
Prelude> 
Prelude> var1
10 :-> Empty
Prelude> 
Prelude> var2
20 :-> (10 :-> Empty)
Prelude> 
Prelude> var3
30 :-> (20 :-> (10 :-> Empty))
```

My question is how to use type constructor in infix form, Can somebody give me an example to understand this ?

Comment: `Int \`Either\` String`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
> :set -XTypeOperators
> data a :-> b = C (a -> b)
> :t C id
C id :: b :-> b
```

<strike>Remember that its name must start with `:` (roughly, `:` is considered "uppercase").</strike> (No longer needed -- see the answer by Cactus for more information)

Otherwise, use backticks, as in `` a `T` b ``.

Comment: Whey is the struck-out text struk-out? Is it wrong, inaccurate, irrelevant, or what?

Comment: I should have read it first, sorry. I'll delete the comment in a while.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on @chi's answer, with recent GHC versions, the syntax of `TypeOperators` has changed somewhat: type constructor names that would otherwise be infix **type variable** names (i.e. symbols without a leading `:`) are still classified as **type constructor** names, meaning the following code works and defines an infix type constructor `+`:

```
{-# language TypeOperators #-}

data a + b = L a | R b
```